# Select returns inconsistant data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How is this possible?

```
insight=> select id from analysis_analysis where status != 'finished' and status != 'archived' and begin_at < '2014-07-28 17:23:27' limit 1;
  id   
-------
 46632
(1 row)

insight=> select id from analysis_analysis where id = 46632 ;
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

I execute theses queries on the same machine / host / server and at the same time. I have the same result for 2 hours.

**edit:**
As requested, here are the explain query:

```
insight=> explain select id from analysis_analysis where status != 'finished' and status != 'archived' and begin_at < '2014-07-28 17:23:27' limit 1;
                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..4.61 rows=1 width=4)
   ->  Seq Scan on analysis_analysis  (cost=0.00..15286.67 rows=3317 width=4)
         Filter: (((status)::text <> 'finished'::text) AND ((status)::text <> 'archived'::text) AND (begin_at < '2014-07-28 17:23:27'::timestamp without time zone))
(3 rows)

insight=> explain select id from analysis_analysis where id = 46632 ;
                                             QUERY PLAN                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using analysis_analysis_pkey on analysis_analysis  (cost=0.41..8.43 rows=1 width=4)
   Index Cond: (id = 46632)
(2 rows)
```

**Edit:**

I tried to rebuild the index, and now I get another error:

```
insight=> select id from analysis_analysis where id = 46632 ;
ERROR:  tuple offset out of range: 0
insight=> select id from analysis_analysis where id = 46633 ;
  id   
-------
 46633
(1 row)
```

**Edit:**

I rebuild the index (again) And now, the the query result is empty (like initially)

**Edit:**

Another query:

```
insight=> select id from analysis_analysis where id >= 46630 and id <= 46635;
  id   
-------
 46630
 46631
 46633
 46634
 46635
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Are these exact copies of your query?

Comment: Please provide the explain plans for both queries just to provide the details of seeing if one is hitting an index and one isn't as Daniel mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @Zane yes
 // Bob I updated the question

Comment: This question [What does: ERROR: tuple offset out of range: 0 mean?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60511/what-does-error-tuple-offset-out-of-range-0-mean) on DBA.se might give further ideas on the problem.

Comment: This error did not occur anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly there's an index on `analysis_analysis(id)`, somehow it got corrupted, your first query doesn't use it, but the second one does and fails because of the data corruption.

Try the second query with:

```
SET enable_indexscan TO off;
```

If the inconsistency comes from the index, the results will be correct this time.

How would an index get corrupted?

- earlier versions of postgresql 9.3.x had some bugs that might cause that, check the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release.html).
- hardware problems.

In SQL, you may use

```
REINDEX INDEX index_name;
```

to rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: Tahnks, but I try what you suggested:

    insight=> SET enable_indexscan TO off;
    SET
    insight=> select id from analysis_analysis where id = 46632 ;
     id 
    ----
    (0 rows)

Comment: I rebuild the index, and now, I have another error. I edited the question